# Loopback Custom Validation Throws Error

Tags: loopbackjs, strongloop

While using Validatable.validate() the Custom function is throwing an internal loopback error.

```
var duplicateConnection = function(err, done, er) {
Connection.find({where: {userId: this.userId, nucleusId: this.nucleusId}}, 
 function(bug, connection) {
   if (!_.isEmpty(connection)) {err();}
 });
};
Connection.validate("userId", duplicateConnection);
```

Error:

```
if (kind !== false) inst.errors.add(attr, message, code);
                                ^
TypeError: undefined is not a function
 at \node_modules\loopback-datasource-juggler\lib\validations.js:550:37
```

Comment: Have you solved this problem? I am facing the same

Comment: Yeah I had to use validateAsync() and it worked.

Comment: yes me too! :) thanks anyway!

Comment: @Gianfra why does this problem occur?  I'm tyring to refrain from using any Async functions.